# Why does the Dassault Falcon 7X's cockpit have ashtrays?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, cockpit, dassault-falcon

While looking at the first implementation of Fly-By-Wire systems, I see that the 7X was the first business jet with fly-by-wire controls.
Looking at the Wikipedia page for the aircraft, I saw this photo of the cockpit and noticed the ashtray in front of the sidestick on either side:

[image: Dassault Falcon 7X Cockpit]

Why would there be an ashtray in the cockpit?
[The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travel-truths/why-do-planes-still-have-ashtrays-/) states that they are still present in aircraft toilets due to a FAA regulation that requires an ashtray be present in the event that a cigarette is lit and needs to be extinguished. However this doesn't cover the flight deck, surely the FAA doesn't assume a pilot will light-up during flight?

Comment: I don't think they are ash trays, probably just a convenient pocket for things like pens, cell phones, flash lights, whatever is in the pilots pockets...

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, for pens, flash lights, etc., I think I'd rather use that holder by the lower front corner of the side window (which seems to be occupied already on both sides). I'm not sure what they are, but I, too, doubt that they are ash trays. **reidi2000,** maybe this question would be better posed by [Edit]ing to instead ask *what they are, and why they are there* rather than *why are there ash trays in the cockpit?* What they are is probably answerable by referencing the POH; *why they are there* would likely require knowledge of aircraft design choices, unless obvious from function.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Above the suspected ashtray there is an image of a cigarette being extinguished, [similar](https://static5.businessinsider.com/image/54d3eb23ecad048328c90e12/why-airplanes-still-have-ashtrays-in-the-bathroom.jpg) to the image embossed on ashtrays in airplane toilets. This gives the impression that the intended use is not as earlier commented by Ron.

Comment: @reidi2000 Fair enough; I couldn't tell at first what that was supposed to depict (and didn't delve too deeply into it, to be honest). Now that you point it out, I agree.

Comment: To Ron's credit, the actual ashtrays aren't present in the picture. The placard is saying "put ashtray here".

Comment: Because Gauloises.

Comment: @user71659 got it right - the Dassault 7X has optional ashtray inserts that fit into those otherwise multi-use stowage pockets.

Comment: At first glance the two ramp workers looked like bobbleheads on the dashboard :D

Comment: @TomMcW That's because the plane is so big that it causes humans to look tiny. If the plane was of a more normal size, then surely the humans would appear much larger. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Lol! That little clip or whatever it is on the dash doesn't help. On my phone screen it makes the guy on the right look like a tiny action figure sitting with his legs hanging over the dash.

Comment: A lot of countries other than the US buy these planes. People smoke. I’m not grasping the mystery.

Comment: Amusing ashtray anecdote .. in 2013, was flying Air Transat VRA -> YYC-> YVR. After landing at YYC and waiting 20+ mins for them to open the cabin frozen door (-30C outside), they discovered the ashtray on the outside door of the front lavatory was missing. After a 15 min search,  They announced they would ground the plane for "missing safety equipment"! Much uproar ensued. After another 10-15 mins, I found it several rows away and over. We could "safely" depart! Canada was first country to ban smoking on airlines in 1989. The A321-200 model I was on launched development in 1995 (flew in '96).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the United States, the smoking ban only applies universally to air carriers on scheduled flights. The [regulation](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr252_main_02.tpl) states

> §252.4   Smoking ban: air carriers. Air carriers shall prohibit smoking on the following flights:
>
> (a) Scheduled passenger flights.
>
> (b) Nonscheduled passenger flights, except for the following flights
>   where a flight attendant is not a required crewmember on the aircraft
>   as determined by the Administrator of the Federal Aviation
>   Administration:
>
> > (1) Single entity charters.
> >
> > (2) On-demand services of air taxi operators.
>
> (c) Nothing in this section shall be deemed to require air carriers to
>   permit smoking aboard aircraft.

So for essentially all of the Falcon's missions, such as Part 91 corporate flights, and private charters under 10 passengers, smoking is permitted, as long as an "adequate number of self-contained, removable ashtrays" are provided (14 CFR 23.853(c)(1) or 25.853(f)).

Said ashtrays from a factory photo:
[image: Falcon jet cockpit]

Closeup found [here](http://aviationweek.com/bca/operators-survey-dassault-falcon-7x):
[image: Ashtray closeup]

Comment: Correct answer, I know many private pilots (all over 60, TBH) that have the habit of "lighting one up" during the less stressful phase of the flight on their personal private airplane, mostly long finals glides on gliders....

Comment: In Europe and the US both AFAIK smoking in the workplace is not allowed. So unless you're flying your own aircraft and it's not owned by a company you wouldn't be allowed to smoke in it. This extends even to one man operations, a guy in England was fined for smoking in his van because it had corporate markings on it (he was self-employed), the same would go for aircraft.

Comment: @jwenting In the US, normal workplace rules, through OSHA, do not apply to aviation. Only FAA rules apply. (Along with train, truck, ship operators)

Comment: In general in the US, rules about smoking (except things like airplanes because "interstate travel" and other reasons) in the workplace, in various buildings, etc. are state or local regulations. There are few, if any, "nationwide" regulations for *everyone* when working. As a more recent example, mask rules vary widely by state/county/etc. and even in (at least most) places in the US where masks are required, if you are in a room by yourself you are not required to wear a mask. Similarly (though sometimes a bit more strict) if you are in a building of your own by yourself smoking is allowed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there are no prohibitions on smoking in airplane cockpits.  Those are indeed ash trays.  Those of you who have traveled to Europe, especially France(!) where this airplane is made, will know that LOTS of people smoke and are free to smoke in many places that prohibit it in the U.S.

Comment: Mind providing a source?